# How to let zabbix know when Java Heap is out of memory on CentOS

Tags: jmx, zabbix

My server is running some java processes (Wowza media Server).
And 1 day, it had been error "out of memory java heap".
I want zabbix to detect this issue to send notify email.
Anyone know about this please help, or just give me an idea.
Thank a lot.

I tried to find some commandline to get java heap size, 
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
but this is not what i want.

I want to get the value of heap memory at the time i run  the command

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMX to monitor JVM metrics (cpu, threads, memory).

> JMX monitoring has native support in Zabbix in the form of a Zabbix daemon called “Zabbix Java gateway”, introduced since Zabbix 2.0.

You can see the documentation  [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring).

Comment: hi gusto, did you do this before?

Comment: -jar /usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless/demo/jfc/Notepad/Notepad.jar this deosn't exist

Comment: On my server, Zabbix Java Gateway is running, but when I add template on zabbix it say "The interface for the item key "jmx [java.lang: type = Memory, HeapMemoryUsage.committed]" does not exist", what did i do wrong?

Comment: @Thor you need to set the `com.sun.management.jmxremote`properties on your running Java application (Notepad.jar is just an example). And I did not configure it myself (at least not in Zabbix, but the principles stay - you can use JMX to read JVM stats). You may check correct naming in the documentation for your current version

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use JVM . For

> The interface for the item key "jmx [java.lang: type = Memory,
>   HeapMemoryUsage.committed]

Does your Host in Zabbix have JMX interface configured?  You can see how it should look like in the documentation link, mentioned above. in section: Configuring JMX interface

p.s mostly it is server_ip and port 6969.